# Dynamic SiteMap presenting the first node, not the correct node

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mvcsitemapprovider

I have a fairly extensive Sitemap defined, using a mix of static and dynamic nodes. When rendering the sitemap (all nodes) it's rendering them all 100% correct, but when rendering as bread-crumb (on the last/deepest child)  it's choosing the first node for all parents and the current node! So basically it's rendering like this for menu:

- Root

  - Level 1 (node #1)

    - Level 2 (node #1)

      - Level 3 (node #1)
    - Level 2 (node #2

      - Level 3 (node #2)
      - Level 3 (node #3)

This is all fine and dandy! But when rendering the bread crumb for what whould have been level 3- node #3 it looks like this (same for L3 #1-3)
Root - L1 #1 -  L2 #1 - L3 #1

Root and L1 is statically defined, L2 and L3 are dynamic. 
It fails on bot L2 and L3 in bread-crumb mode, i.e picking just the first node, not the correct for parents/current node.

I'm trying not to give of to many implementation details here, since that will require me to post a lot of code/Xml, so I'm hoping I don't have to do that... Basically I'm hoping somebody knows what could be causing this and a remedy! Perhaps there is a debug technique I'm unaware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was actually pretty simple... I used the same name for some of the nodes and this created some issues...